# jquery move option to another box and have its value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

hi guys can you help me with this function in jquery the first set of box is functioning the left and right box and buttong but the second set of box is not functioning and dont have its price value i need to fix it that it will function when i click the >> button it will go to the right box and when i click the << it will go to the left box.

**fb.html**

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-3.0.0.js"></script>
 </head>

<body>
   <div>
     <select data-bind="options: foods, optionsText: 'foodName', selectedOptions: foodToBeAdded" multiple></select>
   <input type='button' data-bind="click: addFood" value=' > ' />
    <input type='button' data-bind="click: removeFood" value=' < ' />
   <select data-bind="options: selectedFoods, optionsText: 'foodName', selectedOptions: fo         odToBeRemoved" multiple></select>
     </div>

      <fieldset>
         <legend><p align="left" class=""><b>Reservation Total Price:</b> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;       </legend> <div data-bind="text: foodPriceTotal"></div>
   </fieldset>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var ViewModel = function () {
        self.foods = ko.observableArray([
            { foodName: 'food1', foodPrice: 100 },
            { foodName: 'food2', foodPrice: 200 },
            { foodName: 'food3', foodPrice: 300 },
            { foodName: 'food4', foodPrice: 400 }
        ]);
        self.selectedFoods = ko.observableArray([]);

        self.foodToBeAdded = ko.observableArray([]);
        self.foodToBeRemoved = ko.observableArray([]);

        self.foodPriceTotal = ko.computed(function () {
            var totalPrice = 0;

            ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.selectedFoods(), function (food) {
                totalPrice += food.foodPrice;
            });

            return totalPrice;
        }, this);

        self.addFood = function () {
            console.log(self.foodToBeAdded());
            var foods = self.foods.removeAll(self.foodToBeAdded());

            ko.utils.arrayForEach(foods, function (food) {
                self.selectedFoods.push(food);
            });
        }

         self.removeFood = function () {
           var foods = self.selectedFoods.removeAll(self.foodToBeRemoved());

           ko.utils.arrayForEach(foods, function (food) {
              self.foods.push(food);
             });
          }

          // console.log(self.foods());
         }

         ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
          });
       </script> 
    </body>
   <html>
```

jsfiddle i need to work the got this is a sample of what i need but this is not working
http://jsfiddle.net/kzuMh/1/

Comment: @deepus, your edit is invalid and so I have rolled it back. *fb.html* is *not* part of the code example. Furthermore, whoever reviewed and accepted this edit should have their reviewing privileges removed for reviewing without paying attention... I see PassKit has also noticed your mistakes and already edited them before I could rollback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some duplicated id, this is a bad thing...
I have tested the jdfiddle and it won't work, i think you want to do is something like this:

```
var sLeft1 = $('#s-left1');
var sLeft2 = $('#s-left2');
var sRight1 = $('#s-right1');
var sRight2 = s('#s-right2');
```

with this and modifying ids should work...

http://jsfiddle.net/kzuMh/2/

Comment: it perfectly run:)) tnx this is what i needed tnx:))